# How to copy layer(s) to clipboard in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-3

In QGIS 2.18 there was plugin ["Copy layers and groups to clipboard"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/CopyLayersAndGroupsToClipboard/). It was allowing just in two clicks to copy/paste layer(s) with style and etc. from one project to another.

Is there something similar in QGIS 3.0?

*Animation below shows the plugin in action:*
[image: Animation shows the plugin in action]

Comment: @GermánCarrillo maybe you could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality has been added out-of-the-box for QGIS 3.2. You can now right click a layer or group and select "Copy Layer" (or "Copy Group"), and then right click in the legend of another QGIS window and select Paste Layer/Group:

[image]

Comment: True, but StackExchange answers are forever!

Answer (score 2):

You can drag and drop layers or groups between QGIS windows.

Note, this may not work reliably. As commented by QGIS developer [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) - "*it often results in a kind of "corrupted" layer, which has no features and can't be styled*".  Though I personally have not come across this issue.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work reliably - it often results in a kind of "corrupted" layer, which has no features and can't be styled.

Comment: Thanks for that information @ndawson.  I'll include it in my answer, though I haven't struck it myself.